# why a div can accept before and after selector but an img tag can not?

Tags: html, css

why a div can accept before and after selector but an img tag can not? So how can I define two psuedo elements to my image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::before` and `::after` psuedo-elements appear at the start and end of the content of the element.

An `<img>` is a replaced element, it can't have any content.

Answer (score 0):

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) said, you can not define psuedo-elements for an `img` tag. But if you're so desperately looking for some solution, here is one:

1. create a `div` element
2. set that image of yours to the `background-image` property of the `div`
3. that's it, now you have an `div` element which can take `::before` / `::after` pseudo-elements like normal.